# Is this eval() in python safe?

Tags: python, eval, code-injection

consider this code:

```
from re import sub

input = request.POST['input']
sub_pattern = {'1':"sub('pattern1','txt1',input)",
               '2':"sub('pattern2','txt2',input)",
              }
eval(sub_pattern['1'])
```

is there code-injection in this code?
can you provide POC on this code injection?

Comment: Why would you even bother? You don't **need** `eval` here to accomplish what you're doing.

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? Why not just use `sub(arg1, arg2, input)` and pick `arg1` and `arg2` from your mapping?

Comment: `sub_pattern={'1': lambda i: sub('pattern1', 'txt1', i), ...}`

Comment: Without knowing what the value of `input` is, no, it's not safe.

Comment: @chepner, are you sure? I don't see `input` being substituted into the string, but only referred to. Thus, it looks like it's only constant strings passed to `eval()`, but in closures with different values for `input`.

Comment: Yeah, I `eval`ed too many times in my head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the strings passed to `eval` are constant, with nothing substituted into them, this code is safe. However, it's also a pointless deviation from best practices: There's no legitimate reason to use `eval` here at all.

Assuming that you want to be able to do operations other than `re.sub()`, one approach is to use lambdas:

```
from re import sub

input = request.POST['input']
sub_pattern = {'1': lambda input: sub('pattern1','txt1',input),
               '2': lambda input: sub('pattern2','txt2',input)}
sub_pattern['1'](input)
```

Comment: Depending on how you feel about functional programming, `functools.partial()` might be easier to read.